# excel:changing the symbol and color of a marker based on grouping

Tags: excel, scatter-plot, scatter

I have a dataset that looks like

```
ID    Vehicle_grp    count    mpg  
000     Car           5       10
        Motorbike    20      100
        Other         1       25
001     Car          30       60
        Motorbike    28       45
        Other        85       35
002     Car         100       10
        Motorbike    20      200
        Other         1       65
```

etc.

In excel, how do i change the colors and marker symbols used based on the ID and vehicle group. I would like to change colors based on ID, and use a different symbol for each vehicle group (i.e car is circle, motorbike is triangle, and other is cross)

I don't know VBA, so if theres a way to do this through the menus, that would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure you add each series separately.  Here are the steps (assume Excel 2007 or greater):

1. Insert > Scatter
2. Click the chart > Design > Select Data
3. Add first series.  Series Name = the cell containing 000.  Series X Values = cells for count 5, 20, and 1.  Series Y values = cells for mpg 10, 100 25.
4. Add the second series.  Series Name = cell containing 001.  Series X Values = cells for count 30, 28, 85.  Series Y values = cells for mpg 60, 45, 35.
5. Add the third series according to above.

Following that process gives me:

[image: Chart]

A little clean-up and formatting, gives me:

[image: Clean Chart]

Comment: The only problem is that I have 345 ID's in the real dataset

Comment: The OP wanted colors based on ID and use shape based on vehicle group, this solution applies both color and shape based on ID, rather than on the two separate criteria.